# SQL - Does an object have all the required components?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question in order to really get across what I mean, so I suppose the following example illustrates the question.

Let's say I have a recipe website where users can sign up (data stored in a Users table, with user ID being the primary key) and record ingredients (global ingredient book stored in an AllIngredients table, with ingredient ID being the primary key) that they have in their cabinet (data stored in a UserCabinet table, which links to user ID and ingredient ID).

Then, let's say I have a collection of recipes (stored in a Recipes table, with a recipe ID being the primary key) which are made up of a set of ingredients (stored in a RecipeIngredients table, which links to recipe ID and ingredient ID).

In this scenario, the question I'm asking is how do I determine which recipes a user has all of the ingredients for?  They might have more ingredients than the recipe calls for, which is fine, but they can't have less (i.e. they can't be missing any).  Is this possible with only SQL, or does it require several queries / manipulation using a programming language?

**edit:** The following is the SQL to create the sample tables I'm talking about: http://pastebin.com/N9pqmC2r

Comment: Of course this is possible with SQL; this is what Relational databases are made for.  Since you haven't given any code, we can't tell you the exact details of the query you need.  But it is as simple as doing a joined query.  See https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ to get an idea where to start.

Comment: I added the SQL I would use to create the tables.  I think that the full outer join is closest to what I would want to use but I still am not seeing how to tie that in to finding all of the recipes.  I could perhaps see doing one recipe at a time and seeing if the size of the result set from full outer join matches the size of the result set of that recipe's ingredients, but I'm unsure where I could go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select r.*
from recipes r
join recipeComponents rc on rc.recipe_id = r.id
join userCabinet uc on uc.ingredient_id = rc.ingredient_id
where uc.user_id = ?
group by r.id
having count(uc.ingredient_id) = (
  select count(*)
  from recipeComponents rc1
  where rc1.recipe_id = r.id
)
```

Or

```
select distinct r.*
from recipes r
join recipeComponents rc on rc.recipe_id = r.id
join userCabinet uc on uc.ingredient_id = rc.ingredient_id
where uc.user_id = ?
  and not exists (
    select *
    from recipeComponents rc1
    where rc1.recipe_id = r.id
      and not exists (
          select *
          from userCabinet uc1
          where uc1.ingredient_id = rc1.ingredient_id
      )
  )
```

Or

```
select r.*
from recipes r
left join (
    select rc.recipe_id
    from recipeComponents rc
    left join userCabinet uc 
      on  uc.user_id = ?
      and uc.ingredient_id = rc.ingredient_id
    where uc.ingredient_id is null
) u on u.recipe_id = r.id
where u.recipe_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct u.user_id, r.recipe_id
from recipeComponents r 
left join userCabinet u on r.ingredient_id = u.ingredient_id
where recipe_id not in (
    select recipe_id
    from recipeComponents r 
    left join userCabinet u on r.ingredient_id = u.ingredient_id
    where u.user_id is null
)
```